# How to restrict the user from editing an URL parameter

Tags: php, codeigniter, url-parameters

I am using CodeIgniter. When a user edits the URL parameter, I get a database error.

How can I solve this? In CodeIgniter, I am passing the value 32 in the URL

```
http://xyz.com/esebd2/user/link/link_detail/32
```

If the user edits this as shown below,

```
http://xyz.com/esebd2/user/link/link_detail/323434
```

I get a database error. What to do?

```
function link_detail()

    {

        $this->common_head();
        $lid = $this->uri->segment(4);
        $link_data['link_detail'] = $this->linklist->get_detail_link($lid);
            //above line to retrive value from database
        $this->load->view('user/detaillink_view', $link_data);
        $this->common_footer();

    }
```

Comment: You might want to do at least some simple form of error handling. What does the code look like that parses the URL parameter?

Comment: like the 32 is passed to function link_detail

Comment: How about catching these errors instead of outputting them?

Comment: I could imagine that. Show the code of this `link_detail` function! Basically, you should check whether the ID (the parameter passed from the URL) actually exists in your database before trying to load it, or catch any database error.

Comment: Where is the database query executed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't. And you can't restrict values passed on POST forms on client side too.
Checks must be done server side, and have to be able to deal with all possible values.

Answer (score 5):

You cannot prevent the user from editing the URL. You can only prevent that he/she has access to the resource if he/she is not authorized.

And as for the error message: Any user input should be considered as untrustworthy and should *always* be validated before use. Even if you don’t expect the regular user to change it.

And if an error occurs, don’t output the system’s error message. These are only intended for the developer but not the the user as they can contain sensitive information.